# WPF Application External deployment

Tags: wpf, azure, deployment

We are planning on building an application that will be used within our corporate network and we can also extend this application through internet facing to our contractors.

Can a WPF sandbox application (not XBAP) be deployed externally (for example on Windows Azure) while we can still be able to access it internally through the corporate network?

Or If we deploy this internally, is can we be able to give direct access to contractors outside the domain?

I am new to WPF and have looked through WPF deployment documentations but can't find anything on this. Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: I don't think it is possible the application will live on the client however it can always consume data from azure. Can you elaborate why do you want to do something like that?

Comment: WPF is a thick client (*installed via MSI or ClickOnce*) unless you're using XBAP. Azure is primarily used for hosting server components, not client hosting.

Comment: @bjoshi we want the contractors to be able to use the application without the use of smart cards outside the corporate network so we were thinking maybe if we can deploy externally and let them have access to the functionalities they need.

Comment: @SilverNinja we were considering creating a VM on Azure and hosting the client app not deploying it to Azure server space.

Comment: @activeLearner why do you want to use WPF and not XBAP or Silverlight or something else?

Comment: @bjoshi because Microsoft announced that Silverlight will be deprecated so we are trying to plan going forward in order to avoid re-engineering the system at a later stage.

Comment: @activeLearner I am sorry, to my understanding it is not possible, its complicated anyway. I would really do HTML5, nodejs because I think its simple.

Comment: @bjoshi Thanks for the suggestions, We are currently exploring our options and HTML5 is getting to the top of the list. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I have developed a large scale WPF business application and deployed it using ClickOnce. Although all of the users access it on the local intranet and we don't have any users external to the office, I can confirm that I have used the application whilst at home.

The only thing that you have to worry about is whether all users have permission to access:

1. the deployment server for installation and updates
2. all intranet files and folders that the application uses
3. all database tables, views, stored procedures, etc.

However, if you're not sure, just try it out... it only takes seconds to publish applications using ClickOnce.